# Identifying Military Uniform from Franco Prussian War?

Tags: germany, military-records, photo-identification, prussia

I am looking for information regarding my great-great grandfather Heinrich Rositzky and the military uniform he is wearing, and if a unit or even his rank could possibly be determined by it.

Information on Heinrich Rositzky

Born 1845 in Spieka, Hannover, Preussen, Germany and died in 1916. He was married in 1863 and had children in the years 1864, 1867, 1869, 1870, 1872, 1876 & 1879.

I am assuming he served in the Franco-Prussian War of 1870-1871 and the coat that Heinrich is wearing is a Prussian calvary overcoat, most likely from a Hanoverian dragoon, uhlan or hussar regiment based on the lighter color of the jacket and his location within Germany.

This is a reference photo I found of the 1st Hanoverian Dragoon Regiment
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/79/0d/18790d2ce505fffe910ee41e52881939.jpg

In both photos he is wearing the jacket. In the portrait, you can see his collar more clearly, and in the wedding photo, you can see his sleeves and coat length. He is also wearing a hat which has an emblem on it.

[image: Heinrich Rositzky]
[image: Heinrich Rositzky in lower right]